# Regular expression - from nth word to last

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking for regular expression which allows me to find nth-to-last words in sentence.
I have String:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
```

I would like to get

```
simply dummy text of the printing
```

How the regular expression should look like?

Thank you.

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: You don't need a regular expression

Comment: You need to surround `Lorem...printing` with single- or double-quotes for it to be a string. If want the return value to be a string, it should be quoted as well. That may be the reason for the downvotes. Note that @Rustam assumed you wanted an array returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for PCRE

```
^\w+\s+\w+\s+(.*)
```

should work, you'll need to extract subgroup 1 from the match. If there're less than 3 words, there will be no match.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you use regexp here?

```
n = 3
s = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing'
p s.split[n..-1] #=> ["simply", "dummy", "text", "of", "the", "printing"]
p s.split[n..-1].join(' ') #=> "simply dummy text of the printing"
```

Comment: After re-reading the question (and after upvoting your answer :-)) I'm pretty sure that the OP wants a string (not an array) returned. I say this because `simply dummy text of the printing` is formatted the same as the given string and also in light of the OP's comment on @Peter's answer. You could add tack on `.join`, but that could change the spacing between words.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for comments, I thought it's obvious to use `.join` to return a string, assuming this is a proper "sentence", as stated in the question

Answer (score 1):

I assume the given string contains no punctuation (commas, semi-colons, colons, periods, question marks, etc.) and you want to return a string (that excludes the first two words and any spaces following the second word).

In constructing the regex one must account for the fact that some words are contractions or are hyphenated.

```
r = /
    \A         # match start of string
    (?:        # begin a non-capture group
      [a-z'-]+ # match >= characters in character class
      \s+      # match > 0 characters
    ){2}       # end non-capture group and match it twice
    /xi

"It's tea-time at the Ritz".gsub(r, '')
  #=> "at the Ritz"
```